# How to calculate the mode of a series in Fortran

Tags: fortran

How can I calculate the mode of a series using Fortran?

For example:

```
1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,5
Mode = 3
```

Comment: Now for some constructive critique: What have you got already? Have you even started to program something? People here don't like to do others' homework.

Comment: Yes, if you've been trying for 5 days, you should have some code, however deficient you _think_ it might be. The learning process will be much more beneficial to you if you use that as a starting point. In other words, post the code :-)

Comment: Homework questions are permitted, but they should include the `homework` tag. The asker should also make some effort and show their progress. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score 1):

If your numbers are sorted (as they appear to be), the pseudo-code is simple:

```
set maxval to -1
set maxcount to -1
set count to -1
set lastval to list[0] - 1
for every val in list:
    if val is not equal to lastval:
        if count is greater than maxcount:
            set maxval to lastval
            set maxcount to count
        set count to 0
        set lastval to val
    set count to count plus one
if maxcount is not equal to -1:
    print "mode is " maxval " with count of " maxcount
```

Keep in mind that this will return only the *first* mode if there is more than one.

Answer (score 1):

You can find already made code out there, if you need it and it is not just an exercize; e.g.
[Mode at wiki rosettacode.org](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Averages/Mode#Fortran). If it is an exercize, try first to follow the algorithm given in the other answer.